# In xcode 8, how do I find the calling button from a function

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I've 2 buttons, both of them need to perform similar steps. So, I'd like to move the common functionality to a function. How do I find the button invoking the function, is there a way to read the calling button inside the function?

Comment: You can pass the button as a parameter into the function, is that what you mean?

Comment: This is a good start. http://stackoverflow.com/a/42736846/4475605 If you've got common functionality between the two buttons, then you could write a method containing the common functionality that gets called before/after the switch within the `@IBAction` he suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Simply control-drag from your first button into your view controller's source file and create an IBAction. Set it up to pass in the button as `sender` with type UIButton.

Then, control-drag from your second button to the action you just created.

Now both buttons trigger the same actions and they both pass in the button that triggered them in the `sender` parameter.

You can put different tag values on each button in IB and then query sender.tag to figure out which button was pressed. You can also add outlets to the buttons and then use a switch statement:

```
@IBAction buttonAction(sender: UIButton) {
   switch sender {
     case sender == button1Outlet:
       //code for button1
     case  sender == button2Outlet:
       //code for button2
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response, that's useful info. But, I'm looking to separate the common functionality to a different function and call that function from within the button function you listed.

Comment: Ok, then call your common function from the button action/actions. Using a tag or matching the sender to the outlets will let you tell which button was tapped.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question properly, but you have two buttons that will need to run the same code right? Are these 2 buttons on the same controller? If they are simply write a new function in your controller that does what you want both buttons to do. Then open your storyboard and code side to side with the split view then press control and click on the first button from the storyboard to your code and it will ask you if you want to create an action for this button name the action of this button it will create the function for you, and then do the same for the second button, then have both buttons' functions call that common custom function that you wrote that you want them to do.

Comment: Thank you for the response. From your statements above, that's exactly what I'm trying to achieve. However, my question is how does the function know which button called, like button1 or button2...

Comment: I am not near my Mac right now to show an implementation, but xcode handles that for you. When you create an outlet for your button in the code, xcode connects that function to that button. Thus when you click on that button, accordingly the function and code connected to that button outlet will be called and run. Thus you create an outlet for each button and call that similar function

Answer (score 0):

You can set tag value from InterfaceBuilder as shown in image.
[image]
Or if you are using code from create button then you can set like below.

```
button.tag = 101
```

And in viewController you can check like this

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if sender.tag == 101 {
            //do something
        }
        else {
            //do something
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think the tag would work in my case, will give it a try.